# Redux-toolkit, RTK Query: onCacheEntryAdded doesn't work with fixedCacheKey?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm trying to console.log() on post request success for now, but in general there will be ws subscriptions or state update

```
const [fetchList, list] = rtkApi.useListMutation({
    fixedCacheKey: 'FIXED_CACHE_KEY',
});

...

list: builder.mutation({
  query: () => ({
    method: "POST",
    url: `/some-url`,
  }),
  async onCacheEntryAdded(arg, { cacheDataLoaded, cacheEntryRemoved }) {
    console.log("log me please");
    await cacheDataLoaded;
    console.log("log again");
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source, I can see that [`getCacheKey` doesn't handle that case](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/f7a828255e0612bed0856a0b6d1b9b8d6d6ac30d/packages/toolkit/src/query/core/buildMiddleware/cacheLifecycle.ts#L254) - could you please [open an issue](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues) so we can track and fix this?

Comment: yes, I will open an issue, thank you for fast answer!